# Gmail falsely marks entire thread read

Tags: gmail

This happens when you split a three-way thread and get replies to each split. This is the scenario:

#1 a message
from: foo
to: me, bar

#2 I do reply-all
from: me
to: foo, bar

#3 I do reply to foo, something bar doesn't need to see:
from: me
to: foo

Now, I get a reply to #2 (from bar) and a reply to #3 (from foo). When I read the reply to #2, the reply to #3 is incorrectly marked read as well - which makes me miss it, of course.

I haven't found any complaints about it on the gmail forum, but is this known behaviour?
What would be the easiest workaround to avoid this?